# How do I set a different name to an individual log handler?

Tags: python, logging

I have two log handlers in my code: a `StreamHandler` to write `INFO` level logs from the same module to stdout, and a `FileHandler` to write more verbose, `DEBUG` logs to a file. This is my code:

```
import sys
import logging

log = logging.getLogger('mymodule')
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logf = logging.FileHandler('file.log')
logf.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
log.addHandler(logf)

logs = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
logs.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logs.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
log.addHandler(logs)
```

However, I want the `FileHandler` to also write `DEBUG` info from other modules. I can achieve this if I remove the name from `logging.getLogger()`, but this will also affect my `StreamHandler`, which I only want to print output from my own module.

So is there a way to have either of the handlers use a different name?

Answer (score 1):

There's a `name` attribute available on the base `Handler` class.  I took a look at the [Python source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e2591e4f5eb717922b2b33e201daefe4f99463dc/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L886-L900) and doesn't look like it's used internally so you could manually set each handler to a different name.